# Has lord Rama ever been defeated in battle?

Tags: vishnu, rama

I've seen so many questions similar to this and most of the answers are highly opinionated or confusing. So thought of sharing my logic and opinions to all by explaining nature of Sri Vishnu and who wins the battle between lord Rama and others.

Comment: Rama was never been defeated by anyone. He got injured by Indrajeet's Naagpash (first and last time) just because, Rama knew that Naag pash is Brahma Astra and He can't attack on brahma astra coz of deep respect toward Lord Brahma. So he willingly accepted to be caught in Naagpash coz of Lord Brahma in the same way in which Hanuman willingly accepted to be caught by Indrahit's Brahma Astra in ashoka Vatika. And you can't call this as defeat of Rama coz Rama did this coz of respect toward Brahma, he didn't fight against Nagpash, So this is not defeat.

Comment: This is more of a question to all those claims that lord Rama was defeated or could be.

Comment: @palash debnath - No.

Answer (score 1):

In a common perspective, **Yes**.

But in every other higher/celestial perspective “**NO**”.

**Why?**

Scientifically, if every being in earth gets energy from the Sun and the Sun and all another planet (Dev/Devi’s) gets energy from Sri Vishnu (Paramatman).

But first, you need to understand the nature of Rama (Vishnu). We all know Rama is an avatar of Vishnu the one and infinite. Inspired from computers, think of Rama is an upgraded version of program shortcuts we use, it can contain different names, colors, images or styles but its source is the one where is links. He can scale and hold the power from the source to balance the creation, do whatever it takes to eliminate the corrupt or preserving the correct.

He is Shiva, Brahma, Hanuman, Lav-Kush and he is everything you’ll ever think of. He is who constantly writes and contains the all imaginary universes, Mayas, energies etc.

We all know the entity called “Paramatman” which Sri Krishna explained to Arjun in Mahabharata is in every living being. “Aatman” is a part of “Paramaatman”. In every cycle of creation it moves, it wears bodies of different living beings which metaphorically described in holy Gita as similar to our cloth changing.

Both birth and death is a part of creation, when you are born you take a seat and it vacant when “Aatman” leaves and then some other “Aatman” fills up your space.

If you think this way, that you are a tiny form of composed energy (which we are) in an infinite sea of energy. Everything changes, so drastically that it leaves a blank in one’s mind. We as energy just moving from one to other, constantly influenced by other energies. Birth and death is just another chemical reaction in an infinite universe tube.

And this theory summarizes the source of all energy who is none other than Paramatman Sri Vishnu.

**But why?**

To teach us at our level of understanding. He holds the power and energy to conquer anything. And he does it every avatar. He conquers himself by giving priority to everything other than his name. He chooses to love and devotion before fear. That's why he is greatest.

Also, he is the source of all energy, to which energy he needs to prove his strength? Comparing any fight between "Paramatman" and any other being is like, fighting with your one arm with another and judging who won.

These are my thoughts/opinions, just like others. But why I’m so confident about this answer is I’ve given celestial knowledge priority. It's common knowledge, that celestial beings have so much more IQ and the standards of processing such judgments than a mere human.

*Modifications:*

```
* Please suggest modification if need any or add your theory/opinions. 
* I'll add citations in soon edit.
```

Comment: "It's common knowledge, that celestial beings have so much more IQ and the standards of processing such judgments than a mere human." - no it's not common knowledge, have you heard of the Indra-Ahalya episode in Ramayana? What do you think of Indra's IQ in this case?

Comment: Rama never fight with Lav Kush AND He never got defeated By Indrajita Because when Indrajita shot Naag Paash on Rama then he knew that it is astra of Lord Brahma and he can't reject it, So coz of deep respect toward Brahma he himself agreed to captured in Naagpash, exactly same as Hanuman agreed himself to be captured by Inrajit's  Brahma Astra when he did shot on Hanuman in Ashok vatika to capture him. And Hanuman accepted to be caught coz of respect of Brahma. You can't call this a defeat. Please add this in ur answer, don't mislead.

Comment: If you will not update ur answer with this info then I will have to give down vote.

Comment: @Rishabh Removed those list, real reason of mentioning those to prove my main point as many thinks in those battles Rama partially lost someway. I don't support those claims. Also what do you think of my points?

Comment: @sv. One poor choice of decision doesn't mean celestial beings have less/same IQ as humans. If it's not common knowledge how come you believe those extraordinary tales of various god-goddess or demi-gods or even ancient sages doing extraordinary things?

Answer (score 0):

The one who defeated Lord Rama in the battle
Lord Hanuman fought with Lord Rama to protect "Yayati", the king of Kashi. On the orders of Rishi Vikramaditya, Lord Rama came to kill the King of Kashi. To help the King of Kashi in the battle, Lord Hanuman started reciting Lord Rama. Because of this, Lord Rama's arrows had no effect on Hanuman and Lord Rama had to accept his defeat.

Comment: Welcpme to the site! Can you please provide sources for this? Also, who is Rishi Vikramaditya?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).